# How can I bind events to HTML generated after the page loads?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery `.clone()` to add HTML to my page according to user clicks.

I'd like to add onclick handlers to the newly created HTML.   I know [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) can be used to trigger events on future-created HTML, but I believe that must be written (and executed) *before* the HTML is created.

In this [example code](http://jsfiddle.net/thunderrabbit/Zxq2E/), if the user selects "related_id" from the select list, jquery creates a field where the user can enter ids.  I'd like to add an ajaxy thing here so the user can type the name of the related item instead of its id.  The ajax request will depend on which field the user selected.

Generally speaking, I know how to make ajax requests with jquery, but how do I add the field-specific ajax code to my freshly created HTML?

Comment: Your title is rather irrelevant and I suggest you modify it to more accurately represent your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jsfiddle has a whole lot of code in it, most of which is mostly irrelevant to this question. In any case, if I'm understanding you correctly, what you are seeking clarification on is fairly high-level anyway.

The first thing I would do is ensure you include a common `class` in all of your new elements. Then, you will bind to the click event using `.on()` as follows:

```
$("#parentElement").on('click','.newClass', function() {
    var me = $(this).text(); //gets the specific text from each .newClass element when clicked
    doAjaxRequest( me );
}
```

Note `#parentElement` must exist in the DOM before this click handler is created.

Your `doAjaxRequest` function will be something along the lines of the following:

```
function doAjaxRequest( elemText ) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: elemText,
        ...
    });
}
```

---

Note `.on()` is available for this as of jQuery 1.7. For older versions see the following [options](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

For version 1.4.4. the code would be as follows:

```
$("#parentElement").delegate('.newClass', 'click', function() {
    var me = $(this).text(); //gets the specific text from each .newClass element when clicked
    doAjaxRequest( me );
}
```

Comment: I assumed you want to make the ajax request when the element is clicked. Let me know if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Thank you for the updates; you made a fine answer even better.. worth two green checks!

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a `<script type='text/javascript'> ... your jquery code here </script>` tag along with the rest of your HTML.

Comment: the query will be (slightly) different depending on which item was selected.

Comment: There is a workaround for that. If you create it with a specific id, the code in the script can reference that id as well. Append something like `"<script type='text/javascript'>$(\"" + elementId +"\").stuff()</script>"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just bind the handler to the `$clone` before you add it to the document?

```
$clone.on("change", function(){
  //Do my AJAX  
});
```

Comment: hmmm... in the "Do my AJAX" portion, I'll need to write the ajax based on what was selected; I'll try that and see if it seems like it will work.

Comment: console keeps reporting that .on is not a function, but bind() works fine.

Comment: Yes; we are using version 1.4.4